# Getting Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}" when trying to access properties file on github

Tags: java, spring, cloud

I'm new to Spring cloud, when I'm trying to access properties from github I can't inject "message" value from app-1.properties on github to `@Value("${message}") private String message;` and I'm getting `Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"`
Best part is that 2 days ago it worked properly and yesterday when I run it it didn't anymore even though I didn't do anything, no changes to code etc. Thanks in advance.

git repository link:https://github.com/Krzysiek-lab/demo

client pom file

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

client application.properties

```
spring.application.name=micro
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
server.port=8082
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

client main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

client controller class

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;

    @RequestMapping("/message")
    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

stack trace:

```
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-03-09T11:12:13.589+01:00  WARN 5992 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@7e38a7fe uris = array<String>['http://localhost:8888'], optional = true, profiles = list['dev']]): None of labels [] found
2023-03-09T11:12:14.270+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=9652a333-2b86-385e-9ba8-29ef1e4ea9da
2023-03-09T11:12:14.537+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2023-03-09T11:12:14.544+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-09T11:12:14.544+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-09T11:12:14.615+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-09T11:12:14.616+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1024 ms
2023-03-09T11:12:15.124+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 15 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-03-09T11:12:15.182+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-09T11:12:15.205+01:00  WARN 5992 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
2023-03-09T11:12:15.212+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-03-09T11:12:15.229+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-09T11:12:15.246+01:00 ERROR 5992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:487) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.eagerlyInitialize(RefreshScope.java:126) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.start(RefreshScope.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:113) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:68) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:413) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.example.demo.MicroApplication.main(MicroApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:920) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 27 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Server application.yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          https://github.com/Krzysiek-lab/demo
server:
  port: 8888
```

server main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.datebase=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/moja
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Krzysiek123qweasd.
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.application.name=aplikacja
```

stack trace

```
2023-03-09T10:55:07.135+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 3628 (C:\Users\kignatiuk\Desktop\demo\target\classes started by kignatiuk in C:\Users\kignatiuk\Desktop\demo)
2023-03-09T10:55:07.138+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-09T10:55:07.866+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-09T10:55:08.003+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 129 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-09T10:55:08.214+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=6b7d6cc1-6076-3523-8bcd-f0c941806676
2023-03-09T10:55:08.658+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2023-03-09T10:55:08.669+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-09T10:55:08.670+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-09T10:55:08.761+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-09T10:55:08.762+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1580 ms
2023-03-09T10:55:08.919+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-09T10:55:08.967+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-03-09T10:55:09.201+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-09T10:55:09.348+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@24615687
2023-03-09T10:55:09.349+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-09T10:55:09.382+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-03-09T10:55:10.097+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-09T10:55:10.104+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-09T10:55:10.395+01:00  WARN 3628 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-09T10:55:10.765+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
2023-03-09T10:55:10.845+01:00  WARN 3628 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2023-03-09T10:55:10.865+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2023-03-09T10:55:10.925+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2023-03-09T10:55:10.928+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2023-03-09T10:55:10.949+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2023-03-09T10:55:11.222+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2023-03-09T10:55:11.224+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2023-03-09T10:55:11.226+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2023-03-09T10:55:11.230+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1678355711229 with initial instances count: 2
2023-03-09T10:55:11.233+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application APLIKACJA with eureka with status UP
2023-03-09T10:55:11.233+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1678355711233, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2023-03-09T10:55:11.234+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_APLIKACJA/S0328.tt.com.pl:aplikacja:8888: registering service...
2023-03-09T10:55:11.250+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-09T10:55:11.251+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8888
2023-03-09T10:55:11.263+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_APLIKACJA/S0328.tt.com.pl:aplikacja:8888 - registration status: 204
2023-03-09T10:55:11.279+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.582 seconds (process running for 4.935)
2023-03-09T11:00:10.962+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T11:02:25.157+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-09T11:02:25.157+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-09T11:02:25.158+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-03-09T11:05:10.964+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T11:10:10.975+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T11:15:10.976+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T11:20:10.983+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2023-03-09T11:25:10.986+01:00  INFO 3628 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency><!--?prettify linenums=true?-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

app-1.properties file on github

```
message = my configuration from spring cloud server
```

Comment: I am not very keen with spring cloud. Just one thng comes to my mind, message is declared in the server properties, but you want to use it in the client. Is this a correct approach? Shouldn;t you put your message to application.properties on the client side?

Comment: tried and it that does  work but I don't want to hardcode it in the application.properties file. I want to get propertes from github, what I did is I think the correct approach after all it worked 2 days ago

Comment: From your repository I see that you did some changes. Maybe try to revert to the working version and apply changes one by one to see when the app brakes? Unless someone will come and give better advice and solve your issue.

Comment: The fact that properties are named "app-1.properties" does not change anything? you do not need to cofnigure somewhere the naming of properties file to be this one? "app-1" ?

Comment: in application.yml in git uri is passed url exactly to the app-1 file still nothing changed. When it worked it worked with the file as it is named now

Comment: the thing is that 2 days ago everything worked and when I run the app yesterday it stopped working for some reason, so it stopped working before I made any changes and those changes are not related to the portion of code that's failing

Comment: application.yml is pointing to the repo not the the app-1 file. At least from the code which you posted